# How do I get the HTML title of a loaded page? (PyQt4)

Tags: python, pyqt

How do I get the HTML title of a page that was loaded into a [QWebView][1]? Is it possible?

Comment: Is there more to this than just accessing the "title" property once the page is loaded?

Comment: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwebview.html#title

Comment: Nope, just the HTML title.

Comment: @vgunnu thanks for the heads up — I didn't know about the `.title()` shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the title for the current loaded page in a `QWebView` through the [`.title()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebview.html#title-prop) property, as follows:

```
webview.title()
```

You need to wait til the load has finished for this value to to be correct. You can do this by attaching to the signal. A neat trick is to wrap in a `lambda` (or function) so `browser.title()` is re-evaluated every time the signal is called:

```
browser.loadFinished.connect( lambda _: <fn>( browser.title() ) )
```

`.title()` is a convenience function to access this particular value, but you can also access various other features/attribute of the page. This is done using the the `.page.mainFrame` hierarchy. The attribute `.page` represents the currently loaded page, while `.page.mainFrame` refers to the main frame in it (this is to provide support for frames (`<frame></frame>`) in HTML. The following is equivalent to the first example:

```
webview.page().mainFrame().title())
```

Once you have the [`QWebFrame`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebframe.html) object you can access other properties, such as icons, HTML/text content, size, zoom and scroll state.